# Java Spring boot returns an empty array on a get method from MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

My mongodb got files in it but everytime i use findAll() method from a rest controller, i get back an empty array [ ]

i am new with mongodb and this is something i have never faced before. I used Mongo atlas to create the db and used Mongo Compas to connect to the db.

Help?

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Document(collection = "movies")

public class Movie {

    @Id
    private ObjectId id;
    private String imdbId;
    private String title;
    private String releaseDate;
    private String trailerLink;
    private String poster;
    private List<String> backdrops;
    private List<String> genres;
}


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/movies")
public class MovieController {

    private final MovieService movieService;

    public MovieController(MovieService movieService) {
        this.movieService = movieService;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<Movie>> getAllMovies(){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(movieService.findAllMovies(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}

@Repository
public interface MovieRepository extends MongoRepository<Movie, ObjectId> {
}

public interface MovieService {
    List<Movie> findAllMovies();
}

@Service
public class MovieServiceImpl implements MovieService {


    private final MovieRepository repository;

    public MovieServiceImpl(MovieRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public List<Movie> findAllMovies() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }
}

The application.properties 

spring.data.mongodb.database=MoviesAPI
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb+srv://user:password@cluster0.isclngu.mongodb.net
server.port=9090
```

I tried all i know of. Cant fix it by myself, i need help

Comment: A spin in a debugger should tell you.  Sent a breakpoint in the repository and see why your Mongo query is wrong.  None of the code you posted matters.  It's the repository that you need to look at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I droped the whole db and created a new one. I named everything "movies" from the db name to the collection name, the @Document(collection = "movies") also.
This fixed the issue, I dont know how or why but for someone being stuck on the same problem, try this.